# How to get start index and last index of all the cells having same value in a data Table for a specific column

Tags: c#, datatable

How to get start index and last index of all the cells having same value in a DataTable for a specific column?

Such as if my DataTable looks like below:

```
column1     column2
a             0
a             1
a             2
b             3
b             4
b             5
```

So that I want the output to be start index as 0 for value `a` in `column1` and last index of 2 for value of `a` in `column1`.
Similarly, 3 and 5 for start and last index for value `b` in `column1`.

Comment: But also 3-5 in column1

Comment: You want a query to return

a - 0,
a - 2,
b - 3,
and b - 5?

Comment: No I want a c# logic which could loop through column1 in the datatable and give the start index and last index of similar valued cells inside column1.

Comment: I have an idea, give me a second

Comment: @MasterXD going to the minutes

Comment: Kay, kay, it's here. Writing takes some time you know :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would something like this work?

```
class Index // Edit here
{
    public string value;
    public int first;
    public int last;
}

List<Index> indexes = new List<Index>();

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    Index ind = indexes.SingleOrDefault(i => i.value == row.Cells[0].Value.ToString()); // Remember to set the correct index of the column

    if (ind == null) // Edit here
    {
        ind = new Index(); // Edit here

        ind.value = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString(); // Remember to set the correct index of the column
        ind.first = ind.last = row.Index;

        indexes.Add(ind);
    }
    else
    {
        ind.last = row.Index;
    }
}
```

This should create a list of classes with the variables: value, first and last, which would be the values you're looking for.

I hope this helps.

> Edit: I made some changes to the code, where 'Index' is a class and not a struct. Does this work better?

Comment: I think he is talking about DataTable not gridview

Comment: Oh, shoot. Will fix

Comment: This works well to get the start index but not for last Index.
@Asif I did it for datatable it's pretty much same you know.

Comment: Ok, it works then. What does it say for the last index?

Comment: It's same as that first index.

Comment: @RakeshkumarDas, is it doesn't matter DataTable or GridView?

Comment: What is the value if "ind" when you get to a value the code has seen before? As in when ind.value != null. Does the code even reach "ind.last = row.Index;"?

Comment: I just made an edit to the code. Try and check it out

Comment: Great Job @MasterXD it worked.@Asif.Ali I meant I edited my self for datatable what I meant since bigger work was to get the indexes which MasterXD was focussing.

Comment: Glad I could help:D